# Как сделать проверку формы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

После нажатия Submit идёт проверка формы. Сначала делаются проверки при помощи AJAX. После ответа сервера AJAX запроса делаются остальные проверки. Но форма не дожидается ответа от AJAX и отправляет данные на сервер. Как правильно реализовать, что бы сначала форма не отправляла данные, а после всех проверок отправила, а то совсем туплю. Спасибо

```js
$('#form input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
  // AJAX проверка
  // Получили результат от AJAX и запустили обычные проверки
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="login" value="">
  <input type="password" name="password" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = this;
  // AJAX проверка
  // Получили результат от AJAX и запустили обычные проверки
    form.submit();
});
```

Comment: А как после всех проверок, если нет ошибок отправить данные? Ведь e.preventDefault(); останавливает отправку сразу по нажаnию submit